# Remix Dynamic route on root (/)

Tags: remix.run

I'm creating an app that should follow this rule:

- "/" for homepage
- "/login" for login
- "/user" for user
- "/X" for X represents all my movies genres. For example (/comedy, /fantasy). All genres are been stored in the database.

How to do it using remix? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solved it using Dynamic Routes.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#dynamic-route-parameters

I have created a file called /routes/$page.

```js
import { useParams , useLoaderData} from "remix";
import json from "../../data/movies.json";
import { redirect, Link } from "remix";

export async function loader({ params }) {
  const genre = [
    "comedy",
    "fantasy",
    "crime",
    "drama",
    "music",
  ];

  const { page = "" } = params;
  
  if (genre.includes(page)) {
    //Payload for the page.
    return 'hello';
  } else {
    return redirect("/404");
  }
}

const Page = () => {
  //Recieve payload.
  const data = useLoaderData();

  const params = useParams();
  console.log('client side', data)
  return <div>{data}</div>;
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Please mark you answer as solved ☺️ And glad you figured it our yourself, to me it's always very satisfying to solve problems myself, even more after asking publicly for help 

Comment: "/root/$page" - Aren't routes created inside the /routes directory?

Comment: @PankajParashar yeah, they meant "routes" not "root"